# Recuperar registros de banco de dados por campo data?

Tags: mysql, sql

Como faço para recuperar usuários gravados em um tabela de banco de dados pela campo dt_nascimento através de dois valores que representam a idade minima e máxima dos usuários que deverão ser retornados, a idade minima e máxima nem sempre vem juntas pode-se especificar somente a idade minima, ou somente a idade máxima. É necessário subquery? Obs: o banco é mysql.

Basicamente esta seria a query (onde 18 e 30 são as idades limites) a data de nascimento esta no formato americano AAAA/MM/DD a clausula where é só um exemplo, ela não funciona.

```
SELECT nome, dt_nascimento FROM usuario WHERE dt_nascimento > 18 AND dt_nascimento < 30;
```

Comment: Podes colocar um exemplo da estrutura da tabela e qual o resultado que desejas obter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione 18 anos e 30 anos à data de nascimento e compare com a data actual .

```
SELECT nome, dt_nascimento 
FROM tbl_tabela1 
WHERE DATE_ADD(dt_nascimento,INTERVAL 18 YEAR) <= CURDATE()
AND DATE_ADD(dt_nascimento,INTERVAL 30 YEAR) >= CURDATE();
```

Se dt_nascimento + 18 anos for <= que a data actual é porque tem mais de 18 anos.
Se dt_nascimento + 30 anos for >= que a data actual é porque tem menos de 30 anos.

Comment: ,@ramaral, os operadores (<= e >=) estão corretos mesmos?

Comment: Sim. Exemplo para quem tenha 52 anos: 1962 + 18 = 1980 <= 2015 sim ,tem mais de 18 anos; 1962 + 30 = 1992 >= 2015 não, tem mais de 30 anos.

Comment: ,@ramaral, esta clausula where tambem é valida em PDO (PHP Data Object)

Comment: Não sei PHP, mas julgo que sim.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi podes simplesmente fazer o seguinte:

```
select nome, dt_nascimento 
from tbl_tabela1
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dt_nascimento , CURDATE()) between 18 and 30
```

Estou a assumir que a data esta guardada na base de dados no formato apropriado. Caso não esteja podes sempre converter (CAST) para date ou datetime.

O TIMESTAMPDIFF pode ainda retornar a diferença entre duas datas em DIAS ou MESES, basta substituir YEAR por MONTH ou DAY

Comment: Não leva em consideração o mês e o dia de nascimento, apenas o ano.

Comment: @ramaral, o teste que fiz select timestampdiff(YEAR, '1994-04-15', '2015-04-14') devolve 20 -- select timestampdiff(YEAR, '1994-04-15', '2015-04-16') devolve 21 pelo que penso que esteja a funcionar correctamente

Comment: Peço desculpa, estava enganado.(+1)

Comment: Não tem problema. Depois do teu comentário tambem fiquei na duvida se produzia o resultado correcto ou não. :)